# Task not running?

Tags: .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

The current problem I'm experiencing, is the when the button is pressed, it seems nothing is happening. I'm unsure of why this happens.

Here is the on click method for the button to be pressed:

```
private void computeStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _computeTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    GenerateAll(_computeTokenSource.Token);
}
```

Here is the method called by the on click.

```
private async void GenerateAll(CancellationToken token)
{
    await new Task(() =>
    {
        var total = (long) Math.Pow(36, 6);
        var options = new ParallelOptions {CancellationToken = token};
        Parallel.For(0, total, options, a => GenerateCodeAndHash());
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

Finally this is method called in the `Parallel.For`

```
private void GenerateCodeAndHash()
{
    var result = new string(
        Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, 6)
            .Select(s => s[new Random().Next(s.Length)])
            .ToArray());
    if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(result)) return;
    var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        sb.Append(hash[j].ToString("x2"));
    _dictionary.TryAdd(result, sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that page is being load or not.if Page_Load event is fired then please show your source code.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar It's not a page, it's a windows form. I should have specified that.

Comment: `Math.Pow(36, 6)` will overflow a 64 bit integer. Not the point of the question obviously. `new Random()` will always return the same random number if called on the same millisecond. Synchronize access to _dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the `Task` constructor with `async`/`await`.

In this case, you want to use `Task.Run`:

```
private async void computeStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _computeTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  await Task.Run(() => GenerateAll(_computeTokenSource.Token));
}

private void GenerateAll(CancellationToken token)
{
  var total = (long) Math.Pow(36, 6);
  var options = new ParallelOptions {CancellationToken = token};
  Parallel.For(0, total, options, a => GenerateCodeAndHash());
}
```

For more information, see my [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: And better get rid of the `void` return type as well, although it makes no difference here.

Comment: Good catch; that would be especially important if the calcuation is cancelled. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `Task` constructor creates a `Task` that is not started. If you want to use it, you need to call `Start()` afterwards. But most of the time, you want to create and start the `Task` at the same time, which you can do using `Task.Run()`.

Also, as pointed out by others, you should use `async void` only in event handlers, nowhere else; the `GenerateAll()` method should be `async Task` and you should `await` it from your event handler, which should be `async void`.